# Quicksight User Entered Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible for Quicksight to allow user entered strings as variables for a calculated field?
For example if i have the user enter value x in a filter list (or elsewhere), can I have Quicksight save that variable x so i can create a calculated field such as:
ifelse('item' = x, 1,0)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create calculated fields with parameters. I let you here an example:

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETP5X0OWNi8)